# Whats the best way to handle related data ids using Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

Using [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/), if you have a 'select' editor and want it to link to values 'Male' and 'Female' but underneath male and female are values from another physical database table with id values of 1 and 2 (which are different than the 'row' id), whats the best way to do something like this?

The 'select' editor has ways to specify the display of items in the drop down and a literal display of the selected value, but no place for a hidden (not displayed) underlying ID of the selected value to pass when saving the data.

We could wrap the select data values in divs with a data attribute for the selects values ids and then pass that when updating, but are not sure this is the best option considering how Tabulator works. We could also just pass the raw selected value and then look it up on the server to get the associated ID, but that seems like a lot of overhead and tightly couples the server to the client, which wouldn't work for something like a 3rd party API where we have no server control.

Any thoughts on how best to handle something like this are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. You need to use the lookup formatter to display the text value using the same params as the select editor. This is not obvious since none of the select editor examples in the docs show use of it. Anyway, here is a simple example showing it in both directions. Of course you would want to abstract the data out instead of literally duplicating it, but here to help show the literal use, it is duplicated:

```
{
    title:"Example", 
    field:"example",
    editor: "select",
    editorParams:{
        "1": "Cute",
        "2": "Fine",
        "3": "Scary",
    },
    formatter:"lookup", // display option, but store value
    formatterParams:{
        "1": "Cute",
        "2": "Fine",
        "3": "Scary",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The select editor allows for values to be passed in a number of ways, including specifying both the items value and its user visible label

If you want to show a different lable to the value you want to store, you can pass in an object, where the key of each property is the value that will be stored if it is selected, and the value of each property will be the lable displayed for it in the list.

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    values:{
        "steve":"Steve Boberson",
        "bob":"Bob Jimmerson",
        "jim":"Jim Stevenson",
    }
}}
```

For more complex option lists you can use an array of objects, that allows you to define option groups, and disabled options.

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    values:[
        { //option group
            label:"Men",
            options:[ //options in option group
                {
                    label:"Steve Boberson",
                    value:"steve",
                },
                {
                    label:"Bob Jimmerson",
                    value:"bob",
                },
            ]
        },
        { //option group
            label:"Women",
            options:[ //options in option group
                {
                    label:"Jenny Jillerson",
                    value:"jenny",
                },
                {
                    label:"Jill Betterson",
                    value:"jill",
                },
            ]
        },
        {//ungrouped option
            label:"Other",
            value:"other",
        },
    ]
}}
```

For full details on how to use this editor, checkout the [Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/edit#edit-builtin)

Comment: I read the docs you copied and pasted but they make no reference to how to store/pass IDs for the values. If you set the value for Steve to 1, that it what will display. We want Steve to display in the drop drop and the grid, but we want to pass Steve's ID as the value when saving the selection.

Comment: You can use a value for what is sent back and forth between the database and a label that is displayed. Similarly to an option used in the select HTML element. Are you trying to do something more complex? An editable example of what you are trying to do is best, even if it isn’t inside of Tabulator. A jsfiddle is what I typically recommend. It helps understand your problem.